# Can we commit on branch that's already been merged with master?

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging

I have a branch, say "**XYZ**", I worked and did a few commits on that branch and later merged it with my master branch. Now, I want to do some more changes in my code and want to use that same branch. I have not deleted the branch.

Can I use the same branch again? Can I then merge the new commits with master again? Or is the only solution to create another branch?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can still work on that branch as it still exists.

The [git-merge](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) documentation says:

> Incorporates changes from the named commits (since the time their
>   histories diverged from the current branch) into the current branch.

You can continue working on your branch and then when you merge with master again, it will bring the commits that are missing on master.

Comment: before reusing that branch, what are the commands to be run ?